# How to find specific text under multiple spans in Beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to extract the IPA keys under the French section of the wiki page:
https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/son#French

I want only the data in the french section.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd


def main():
    
    test_url_page = 'https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/son#French'
    
    req = requests.get(test_url_page)
    content = req.text

    ipa_data = []
        
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
    
    french_section = soup.find('span', {'class':'mw-headline'} and {'id':'French'})
    
    for fr_ipas in french_section.find_next('span', {'class':'IPA'}):
        ipa_data.append(fr_ipas)

    fr_ipas_all = french_section.find_all_next('span', {'class':'IPA'})
```

find_next only returns the first element under the french section.
find_all and find_all_next returns a list of all the elements within the html.
I just want the elements under the french section. There are multiple IPA keys under the french section.

Answer (score 1):

Close to your goal, but you have to check if the next elements
or `.find_next_siblings()` has your IPA element and break the iteration until there is a `<hr>`, that defines the next section:

```
french_section = soup.find('span',{'id':'French'}).parent
for tag in french_section.find_next_siblings():
    if tag == 'hr':
        break
    if tag.find('span', {'class':'IPA'}):
        ipa_data.append(tag.find('span', {'class':'IPA'})
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def main():
    test_url_page = 'https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/son#French'
    req = requests.get(test_url_page)
    content = req.text

    ipa_data = []
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
    french_section = soup.find('span',{'id':'French'}).parent
    for tag in french_section.find_next_siblings():
        if tag == 'hr':
            break
        if tag.find('span', {'class':'IPA'}):
            ipa_data.append(tag.find('span', {'class':'IPA'})) 
        
    return ipa_data

main()
```